# PyNaCl building problems

Tags: python-3.x, pip, discord.py, pynacl

So I'm trying to download discord's API into my venv with pip but it's failing to build PyNaCl. It says that the error is that the 'make' utility is missing from PATH but I just added it in my environment variables and tried running it on cmd to make sure it's properly installed. Any ideas on what could be causing the issue?

I'm running windows 10, python 3.9.1, and pip 20.3.3
[Here is the error message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyATB.png)

Note: I can perfectly install the discord module without voice support, however, I want to make use of its voice features and I cannot understand why it's failing to install.

Answer (score 3):

> 'make' utility is missing from PATH

---

**The cause of this error**

This error is caused by a **BUG** in `setup.py` of `PyNacl` source code.

However, even if you fix it, you will encounter more problem since that source code does not intend for building on windows.

If you just want to install `PyNacl`, see the next section.

If you want to know the detail of that **BUG**, see the last section.

---

**Installing PyNacl**

After Sep 14, 2020, `pynacl` has abi3 pre-built wheel, so `pip install pynacl` will automatically download and install it. You don't need to build `pynacl` by yourself.

- You can also manually download
  [`PyNaCl-1.4.0-cp35-abi3-win_amd64.whl`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/a6/1e94dd44f8b4a1be93a7cf5f61e5998475acd44b30cb49aee0beb5b62cc7/PyNaCl-1.4.0-cp35-abi3-win_amd64.whl) and `pip install PyNaCl-1.4.0-cp35-abi3-win_amd64.whl` (in download dir).
- If you get an error, you can use `pip install -U pip` to upgrade pip and try again.
- If you *still* get an error, you can use `pip debug -v` to check compatible tags:
- If the compatible tags have the "win_amd64" postfix, there should be a "cp35-abi3-win_amd64" tag, and `pip install` should succeed.
- If the compatible tags have the "mingw_x86_64" or "mingw_x86_64_ucrt" postfix, you must build `pynacl` by yourself (or install win_amd64 python).

`pynacl` lists `libsodium` as a dependency. Fortunately, you don't need to build `libsodium` (which needs `make`, causing the error you encountered).

- You can download pre-built `libsodium` from https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/.
- download: https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.18-stable-mingw.tar.gz
- unzip .gz (you can use 7-zip or peazip) and copy the directories ("bin", "lib", "include") in /libsodium-1.0.18-stable-mingw.tar/libsodium-win64 to your `mingw` installation directory(which also contain "bin", "lib", "include")
- finally, use bash (such as git bash): `SODIUM_INSTALL=system pip install pynacl`.

Then pip will use PEP517 to build and install `pynacl` for you with pre-built `libsodium`. Or, you can build by yourself (download the source code from pypi, and in the source code directory):

```
SODIUM_INSTALL=system python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

With cmd or powershell, you cannot set environment variable in the bash style. You can use following instead:

```
$env:SODIUM_INSTALL="system";pip install pynacl
```

---

**Details of the bug**

The error is raised here:

```
if not which("make"):
    raise Exception("ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH")
```

And the function `which` is implemented with a **BUG**:

```
def which(name, flags=os.X_OK):  # Taken from twisted
    result = []
    exts = filter(None, os.environ.get('PATHEXT', '').split(os.pathsep))
    path = os.environ.get('PATH', None)
    if path is None:
        return []
    for p in os.environ.get('PATH', '').split(os.pathsep):
        p = os.path.join(p, name)
        if os.access(p, flags):
            result.append(p)
        for e in exts:
            pext = p + e
            if os.access(pext, flags):
                result.append(pext)
    return result
```

In Python3, `filter` returns an iterator, not a `list` (python2's `filter` returns a `list`). Thus, the "exts" will be "exhausted" in the first iteration. You can replace `filter(...)` with `list(filter(...))` to fix it.